# Performing projections with distance different to Euclidean

Tags: euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

This is the first time I'm asking a question on math section of stackexchange, so please excuse me if this isn't the right place for such a question.

I'm a programmer studying about an algorithm which embeds the notion of projection of points. [Here](https://seer.lcc.ufmg.br/index.php/jidm/article/viewFile/99/82) is the concrete paperwork. In the spirit of math section, I'm not expecting from anyone to spend time on the algorithm itself, but I am interesting in a concrete part, that talks about these projections to speed up the algorithm. That part is located on page numerated as 225.

What confuses me is this - does the distance used in projection need to be Euclidean, or any other distance can be used?

Concretely, I'm interesting in something called [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) as a distance measure. This distance measure is used mostly to find the similarities between to signals, where signals may be shifted or skewed. It finds the optimal alignment between the signals. It actually uses Euclidean distance measure to find distance between two points, but it creates a matrix which is used to find the best alignment.

Can anyone please explain would it be reasonable to use such a distance, and that the projections are still valid?

This projection is used to find the "most central object in cluster". On page 226 you could see how this projection is actually used.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The distance does not have to be Euclidean, but it cannot be DTW.

The distance needs to be a metric, and DTW is not a metric.

There are other ways to quickly cluster under DTW; for example, see "Dynamic Time Warping Averaging of Time Series allows Faster and more Accurate Classification" ICDM 2014

There are ways to approximately embed DTW into a metric space, but it is not clear that it is worth the effort.

Source: I have more papers on DTW than anyone else in the world. Eamonn

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. Could you please elaborate a bit more about the ways you mentioned to embed DTW into a metric space, and what do you mean that it isn't clear is it worth the effort? The thing is, I have implemented the algorithm I mentioned with DTW already, but I wasn't sure if it is a valid approach (and unfortunately didn't have knowledge required about the metrics), so I would like to "save it", if possible, and later try with the paperwork you have provided.

Comment: Actually, you already answered me on cross-validated (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143300/fames-in-case-of-dynamic-time-warping), you did mention the same paperwork, but you didn't mention the problem with metrics... At that moment I thought that it is just an alternative solution you are offering, and not that you are saying that is impossible to use it. What consequences might my mistake have? Will it be a total waste, or is it matter of clustering quality?